# Looking for a image slide for wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, slider

Helo,

i am looking for a simple image slider (left/right) and simple auto play modus to use in a wordpress blog without using it as a plugin since all images will be images cached from flickr . So the images should be defined as normal img tags for the slider to recognize the images.

the few i tested like nivo/simple slide all collide/conflict with the jquery plugin and prettyphoto plugin i also use for lightboxing. Any suggestion for a slick and slim slider that could work? i want it to also work with prettyPhoto for popping up the image.

thx

Answer (score -1):

try using orbit slider from zurb's foundation framework http://foundation.zurb.com or their github http://www.github.com/zurb/foundation

Comment: Seriously? Who down votes a two year old answer?... granted now a days revo slider is amazing but yeah...